# PHP syntax for a loop

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to turn the following PHP into a loop. I've done loops in the past but this one is proving difficult to get the syntax right.

```
    $answer1= $_POST['answer1'];
    $answer2= $_POST['answer2'];
    $answer3= $_POST['answer3'];
    $answer4= $_POST['answer4'];
    $answer5= $_POST['answer5'];
    $answer6= $_POST['answer6'];
    $answer7= $_POST['answer7'];
    $answer8= $_POST['answer8'];
    $answer9= $_POST['answer9'];
    $answer10= $_POST['answer10'];
    $answer10= $_POST['answer10'];
```

So far I've been working with a loop shown below.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $answer . $x = $_POST['answer' . $x];

    $b = "\$answer" . $x;

    $a = $b . "= \$_POST[" . $b . "]";
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the { } operator  for dynamic eval of php content for dynamic var generation

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
  ${"answer" . $x} = $_POST['answer' . $x];

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: You should elaborate on that suggestion.

Comment: @Niklesh   . compatc is a good function .. the result is an array  i have answer  to the OP request ..  that seems need diffrent  vars ..

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the `$answer` and the `$x` with `{}`, so it will create the variable based on the value of the other two variables

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    {$answer . $x} = $_POST['answer' . $x];

    $b = "\$answer" . $x;

    $a = $b . "= \$_POST[" . $b . "]";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, just wanted to bring to your attention that it doesn't like the {$answer . $x} (line 2) giving the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in